# Having problems with python putting 2 backslashes in path

Tags: python-3.x, directory

I have this problem that python puts 2 backlashes in an path and I don't understand why.
Here is the code:

```
    with open(os.path.join("Users", "Kasutaja", "AppData", "Local", "Growtopia", "save.dat"), 'r+') as f:
        file_data = f.read()
```

It gives me this=

```
C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe "C:/Users/Kasutaja/Desktop/Growtopia Hack.py"
Game not found! Make sure to open this before Growtopia
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\Desktop\Growtopia Hack.py", line 61, in <module>
    with open(os.path.join("Users", "Kasutaja", "AppData", "Local", "Growtopia", "save.dat"), 'r+') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Users\\Kasutaja\\AppData\\Local\\Growtopia\\save.dat'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I don't think the double-slashes are your problem. Can you actually navigate to 'Users\\Kasutaja\\AppData\\Local\\Growtopia\\save.dat' in a file explorer? Are you on Windows, Mac, or Linux?

Comment: I was told that C: wasnt needed when using os.path.join

Comment: Hmm. `os.path.exists(os.path.join("Users", "m210028", "ntuser.ini"))` is `False`, but  `os.path.exists(os.path.join("C:\\", "Users", "m210028", "ntuser.ini"))` is True. You need the double backslash there to escape the character. I'd say you DO need `C:\\` there.